# How I can deal with captcha images manually or through automation using selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, captcha

Hi Can anyone guide me how to deal with Captcha images in selenium. The solution mostly people recommended is to enter captcha manually but by validating captcha images manually after consuming a lot of time it displays error message that "please try again" or if I try another voice method it says you are using automated script. So how can I deal with it manually or through automation??

Comment: @Boy I tried to enter manually but it is not recognizing because captcha  knows that it's automated script. . is there anyway to deal manually?

Comment: To automatically solve captcha you need image recognition library, which is not trivial task. To make it half automatic (manual captcha) you should probably add some delay between HTTP requests, that could solve the problem.